# How to return DateTime.Today as a FieldNullValue in FileHelpers

Tags: c#, datetime, filehelpers

I'm trying to set the `FieldNullValue` for a `DateTime` variable in a `FileHelpers` class to the Today value (so if when I read the .csv there is no entry, it defaults to Today's date). The code I've tried is:

```
[FieldOptional]
[FieldNullValue(DateTime.Today)]
public DateTime DATE;
```

However I get the error

> "Error    1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof
>   expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
>   type".

Please can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Today` is never a constant, as it is constantly changing... I suppose you could use a magic value which you will have to manually look for and convert later.

Comment: Is there not someway to take a copy of the Today value at the time the code is run perhaps and use that as a constant value? I'm used to Python where the DateTime.Today() method returns a fixed DateTime once called.

Comment: Does defining `static readonly DateTime defaultDate = DateTime.Now();` and then using it like `[FieldNullValue(defaultDate)]` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious approach would be

```
[FieldOptional]
[FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Today.ToString("M-dd-yyyy"))] 
public DateTime DATE;
```

But it seems that *FieldNullValueAttribute* is unable to evaluate expressions like is the case for *DateTime.Today.ToString()* , so the only way to go for you is to hardcode a fixed date as string (not what we want in our code):

```
[FieldOptional]
[FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime), "5/15/2015")] 
public DateTime DATE;
```

Comment: That avoids the original error but instead throws: "The best overloaded method match for 'FileHelpers.FieldNullValueAttribute.FieldNullValueAttribute(System.Type, string)' has some invalid arguments" and also throws "Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string'". Why does it seem to want a string as a null value as opposed to the same variable class (DateTime) as I'm then referring to?

Comment: What happen if you use DateTime.Today.ToString("M-dd-yyyy") ?

Comment: [FieldOptional]
        [FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Today.ToString("M-dd-yyyy"))]
        public DateTime DATE; <--- this now throws the original error about parameter types

Comment: The only workaround for you here is to hardcode a fixed date as string but I dont think is what you want. [FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime),"5/15/2015"]

Comment: Yes that at least lets me compile my code which I couldn't before, thanks! You're right in that it's not the ideal solution (a hardcoded 'today') but it's halfway.

Comment: This appeared in the low quality review queue. I suspect the reason is because you answered only with code, and no explanation. I recommend editing your answer to show some of the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Looks great! It wasn't me who flagged it, but since you did give a good answer I wanted to make you aware of it, so that you don't face downvotes and flags against you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Today is not a constant value, for datetime values you have to use typeof operator like below, here again you have to specify a fixed date i.e. a constant value

`[FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime), "2005-1-1")]`

or the second approach could be to declare DATE as nullable type

```
public DateTime? DATE;
```

And later create a property for the conversion

```
public DateTime? DATE     {
   get 
    {
    if (DATE.HasValue)
        return DATE;
    else
        return DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is related a variable, not for a property.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectingKamlesh's answer is correct though his example confuses things as he's named the property the same as the field.

Yes, your problem is related to a variable but what you do is have the variable as a private/backing field to the property. Since FileHelpers by default uses only fields not properties, you load into the private field but access the property which does the conversion for you.

In my example below, we have a system that uses only integer values with no decimal places as its implied in a string form with an alpha for the first (or last) digit.

So to get to a proper format with the correct number of decimal places that can be used correctly I use the following code:

```
    [FieldOrder(59),FieldAlign(AlignMode.Right, '0'),
     FieldConverter(typeof(SynergyHelper.DecimalConverter)),
     FieldFixedLength(5)]
    private Nullable<System.Int32 > m_CLOYAL;
    public Nullable<System.Decimal > CLOYAL
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_CLOYAL.HasValue)
                return (System.Decimal)((System.Double)m_CLOYAL / Math.Pow(10, 2));

            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            m_CLOYAL = (System.Int32)(((System.Double)value.GetValueOrDefault()) * 
                                                      Math.Pow(10, 2));
        }
    }
```

So as you can see the backing field, untouchable by you but the property is usable.  For me, I go through the extra step of the DecimalConverter (which is my own conversion code) as well but as you know Attributes must use static values outside of the property/field/class they are against.